# Is a private class parameter accessed through synchronized methods considered a 'synchronized object'?

Tags: java, synchronization, singleton

Is a private static parameter of a singleton considered a 'synchronized parameter' if the access to it is exclusively through synchronized methods?  What if it was public? I don't think it is in either case because I believe you can only put the synchronized keyword on labeled blocks and methods, not params.  If the param is mutable in any way (reflection?) even though access is restricted, then it risks being out of sync if not used through the synchronized methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no well-defined term of "synchronized object" or "synchronized parameter". You may find some people *using* either of those terms, but they're not part of the language specification or even commonly used with a specific meaning, in my experience.

Bear in mind that the monitor you synchronize on is conceptually entirely separate from the aspect of code it's trying to synchronize. For example, it's common to have an object *just* for the purpose of synchronization, as a "guard" for all mutable state in a type.